# Some WordPress pages are not loading. Contents are not showing

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I'm trying to view some of my customized pages in WordPress theme, those are not loading. Keep loading but contents are not appearing. http://test.sourceone.lk/news/
http://test.sourceone.lk/services-2/
Anyone have a solution please?

Thank You.

Comment: Don't forget to up vote if any answers helped ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the theme. The content is loading, but the preloader overlay doesn't disappear. Have you contacted the theme developer about the issue?

If you're not too bothered about having the preloader working/displaying or you just want a quick/temporary fix, you could add some custom CSS code to hide it:

```
.preloader {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But Wordpress Admin bar is disappeared now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
    jQuery('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

This is because the `fadeOut` event doesn't work. Your content loads, but the `preloader` does not disappear.